# storing values from JSON.stringify to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, post

I am trying to store values from html form and stored/send via JSON.stringify to my php file, and then my PHP file write those values to DB.

So far i've managed to receive the $_POST values but is it in array, like this:

```
["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"]

This is my PHP file now:
$array = $_POST["input"];
$i_ment = $array[0];
$odd_ment = $array[1];
$em_ment = $array[2];
$mobi_ment = $array[3];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO team VALUES ('$i_ment', '$odd_ment', '$em_ment', '$mobi_ment')")
```

But the values that comes to db are still in arrow, like this:

```
["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"],["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"],["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"],["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"]
```

Comment: if you transmit your data as json, you have to *decode* it first. i don't see any  `json_decode` in your code. also: **don't** use `mysql_`-functions as they are deprecated and in PHP7 removed. instead use `mysqli_` or `pdo`. also: **don't** include user data directly into your queries, it makes your code vulnerable for SQL injections, use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: gosh, I feel stupid. Thank you for your detailed explanation about php security and for all the help with json :) You can put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when receiving JSON-data, it is just a string, not an array.

you have to decode it before you can actually use it:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST["input"], true);
```

note the true, which tells PHP to create an associative array instead of an object.

also: you shouldn't use `mysql`-functions, which are deprecated and in PHP7 removed; and your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

both `mysqli_` and `PDO` provide parameterized queries which protect you from this kind of attack.